# TypeError in reactnative Image tag

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add a logo to react-native code using Image tag but after I add Image tag it gives me below error

TypeError: (0, _reactNative.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNative.default)("./../assets/logo.png")', '(0, _reactNative.default)' is an instance of Object)
* component\Login.js:12:34 in render
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11581:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11509:4 in updateClassComponent
- ... 18 more stack frames from framework internals

below is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Image from "react-native";
import require from 'react-native'
import {ImageBackground} from "react-native";

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image sorce={require('./../assets/logo.png')}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    logoContainer:{
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
    },
});
```

my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './component/Login'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Login/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

so what is wrong here?

Comment: thank you I just corrected it sir but error not gone

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong Image import.

Use it like this:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
const myImageSource = require('./../assets/logo.png'); // Double check that you have the image at that path
```

Fix the typo from image source:

`<Image source={myImageSource}/>`

If still not working add full content of your files and RN version to your question.

Comment: thank you sir but those methods does not working Finally I change my App.js file as below                                                                                                export default class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
        <View >
          <Text>Hello t</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}                                                                                                                           now it is display the text, but when I add <Login/> gives me same error